# AppSync Enhanced Filtering resolver

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

My schema:

```
type Mutation {
    createOrder(order: OrderDTO!): Order!
}

type Subscription {
    onNewOrder(minimumPrice: Float): Order @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createOrder"])
}
```

My Lambda resolver for `createOrder` mutation:

```
exports.handler = async function (event: OrderEvent): Promise<OrderWithPrice> {
    const order = await orderRepository.createOrder(event);
    ...
    return {
        ...order,
        totalPrice: await calculateTotalPrice(order)
    }
};
```

The user should pass `minimumPrice` parameter on subscription and subscribe to only orders with `totalPrice` higher than minimal. Enhanced Filtering is required for that.

AWS docs recommend to create `request` and `response` functions with `extensions.setSubscriptionFilter` but in this case AppSync won't be able to use my handler (it cannot have 1 handler and 2 additional exported functions).

What is a proper way to use Enhanced Filtering for my case?